# Это вообще тестовое задание на обычные курсы по Python-y или это задание на позицию Senior?

Tags: python

Python
Задача на лайки

Требования к выполнению: предоставить готовый результат  ссылкой на GitHub репозиторий

Срок на выполнение: 1-2 дня

Написать программу, обрабатывающую лайки под постами в соц-сетях.
Примеры возврата функции.

```
[]-->  "Это никому не нравится"
["Андрей"]-->  "Андрей лайкнул это."
["Андрей", "Жанна"]-->  "Андрей и Жанна лайкнули это."
["Андрей", "Жанна", "Катя"]-->  "Андрей, Жанна и Катя лайкнули это"
["Андрей", "Жанна", "Катя", "Макс"]-->  "Андрей, Жанна и ещё 2 человека лайкнули это"
```

В случае если в имени есть цифры, не алфавитные символы или имя длиннее 10 символов - вместо результата возвращаем
текст с ошибкой (составить по собственному усмотрению), т.е. реализовать валидацию данных.

Создать фласк-приложение с одним ендпоинтом - "/likes", которое выдаст соответствующий результат по запросам, т.е.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/likes?names=Андрей,Жанна,Катя,Макс --->  

{
"error": False,
"data": "Андрей, Жанна и ещё 2 человека лайкнули это",
"error_message": None
}

http://127.0.0.1:8000/likes?names=Андрей235,Жа__@$6SF?,Катя ---> 

{
"error": True,
"data": None,
"error_message": "*Текст сообщения об ошибке*"
}
```

Просто чтоб было понятно, мне скинули базовую книгу "Укус Питона" где Пайтон для начинающих, а потом скидывают это тестовое задание.

Comment: Вы пытались сами выполнить задание?

Comment: Вообще башка не варит как можно это сделать

Comment: Я часа два сидел пытался понять и сделать это задание

Comment: По сути, все что здесь требуется это сформировать сообщение для вывода рядом с количеством лайков. Причем всего у вас может быть только 5 кейсов.

Comment: Вам ведь под силу сформировать сообщение `Это никому не нравится`?

Comment: `Андрей лайкнул это.` что насчет этого?

Comment: Когда начинаются проблемы и в чем они состоят?

Comment: так вам подсказку даже дали в виде списка.

Comment: Проблемы начинаются походу с самого понимания задания, я возможно буквально понял задание и поэтому пошел в твиттер доставать с поста лайки (реально пытался с поста какт достать количество пользователей которые лайкнули)

Comment: я сначала тоже так подумал:)

Comment: Сергей Ш, так я вас скажу что я пытался сделать это почти 2 часа, чисто искал способ как достать лайки с поста, и чисто из-за безысходности сюда пишу

Comment: Всё равно не могу понять логику как сформировать сообщение

Comment: Конкатенация, join и условные выражения / switch на основе количества переданных имён

Comment: Михаил, ещё не удобный вопросик, имена мне нужно самому придумать и добавить? или надо использовать которые данны 
names=Андрей,Жанна,Катя,Макс
names=Андрей235,Жа__@$6SF?,Катя

Comment: "надо использовать которые данны" точнее который приходят по запросу в параметре name

Comment: - Сергей спасибо

Comment: Напишите в google: Flask - там много примеров и описание

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Первая задача, вроде не сложная. Простейшая работа со списками. Касательно валидции, когда-то делал подобную задачу, вот код:

```
#Login's validation
list = []
list += range(97, 123) #Permissible symbols (ASCI codes)
list += range(48, 58)

def valid_log(login):
    for i in login:
        n = ord(i.lower())
        if n in list: #Limiting the length of the name
            letter = True
        else:
            letter = False
    if len(login) >= 2 and len(login) <= 16 and letter:
        back_send = request_status[1] #The check is passed
    else:
        back_send = request_status[6] #The check is not passed
    return back_send
```

код далеко не идеальный, но с задачей справляется. А касательно, последнего, самому интересно, как сделаете. Как закончите, будьте добры, напишите ваше решение.

Answer (score -1):

Для Flask задачи (я под виндой делал)

1. Запускаем консоль (cmd.exe)
2. Создаём окружение: python -m venv c:\projects\taskLike
3. cd c:\projects\taskLike
4. запускаем Scripts\activate.bat
5. pip install flask
6. создаём каталог app (mkdir app)

Структура каталога taskLike:

```
taskLike
 +-- Include
 +-- Lib
 +-- Scripts
 +-- app
 |     +-- __init__.py
 |     +-- routes.py
 +--- likes.py
```

Файл likes.py

```
from app import app
```

Файл `app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import routes
```

Файл `app/routes.py`

```
import re
from app import app

from flask import request, jsonify

@app.route('/likes', methods=['GET'])
def likes():

    error = False
    error_message = None
    data = None

    names = request.args.get("names", default="", type=str)

    names = names.split(',')
    names = list(map(str.strip, names))
    names = [x for x in names if len(x) > 0]

    if validate(names) == True:

        cou_names = len(names)

        if cou_names == 0:
            data = 'Это никому не нравится'
        elif cou_names == 1:
            data = f'{names[0]} лайкнул это.'
        elif cou_names == 2:
            data = f'{names[0]} и {names[1]} лайкнули это.'
        elif cou_names == 3:
            data = f'{names[0]}, {names[1]} и {names[2]} лайкнули это.'
        else: # cou_names > 3:
            data = f'{names[0]}, {names[1]} и ещё {cou_names-2} человека лайкнули это.'
    else:
        error = True
        error_message = 'Плохие имена'

    return jsonify({'error': error,
                    'data': data,
                    'error_message': error_message})

def validate(names: list) -> bool:
    for name in names:
        if len(name) > 10 or re.search(r'[\W|_]', name):
            return False
    return True
```

Запускаем из консоль и вводим:

set FLASK_DEBUG=1

flask run --port=8000

смотрим браузером

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/likes?names=Петя,Evgen](http://127.0.0.1:8000/likes?names=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8F,Evgen)

Всё остальное доделываем как надо